# Android setVisibility not working in PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I'm trying to hide and show part of my view in my PagerAdapter item but it doesn't do anything, not GONE, VISIBLE, or INVISIBLE.

```
public class FeedPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private final String KEY_GLOBAL_PREFS = "global";

    @BindView(R.id.item) ImageView image;
    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar) ProgressBar progressBar;

    private final SlideActivity host;
    private List<Thing> items;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private int postition;

    public FeedPagerAdapter(SlideActivity host, List<Thing> items){
        this.host = host;
        this.items = items;

        sharedPreferences = host.getSharedPreferences(KEY_GLOBAL_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(host).inflate(R.layout.item_slide_reddit_post, parent, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

Here's the item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src:"..."/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how the adapter is set up from the host activity:

```
adapter = new FeedPagerAdapter(SlideActivity.this, List<> of items);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Any help would be awesome

Comment: I would not be surprised that if you set a breakpoint inside `instantiateItem`, you will find that `progressBar` is null

Comment: Just checked, it's not null. It appears on screen fine, I'm trying to get it to go away by changing it's visibility but when I change it nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that using `Butterknife` or standard `findViewById` to setup `ProgressBar` item doesn't work to update the view, not sure why, maybe someone can explain. I solved by seeking out the actual item every time it's visibility needs to be changed in `PagerAdapter` like so:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(host).inflate(R.layout.item_slide_reddit_post, parent, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at that item.xml again, it looks for me ur image is match parent, and ur progress bar is wrap content. change image to wrap_contet and make sure progress bar appears on display!

Comment: It appears all the way in the upper left corner. I was planning on fixing before I posted but I forgot

Answer (score 0):

Add a `notifyDataSetChanged()` after the `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` maybe the line `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is happening before you set the progressBar visibility.

Comment: Ok, that sort of worked. It made the progress bars go away as intended on all the pages to the left or right as well as if I leave and return to the page I started on. But it doesn't remove it from the view if I stay on the start page without paging left or right and paging back    (edit): `notifyDataSetChaned()` isn't what helped, I guess it worked on adjacent pages as intended before also

Comment: So check when you need to notify the adapter that the info has changed, that's your problem.

Comment: Sorry, check the edit I made just now to the comment above you

Answer (score 0):

I remember to change the ProgressBar states, you should always use runOnUiThread()

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // implement View changes.
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably good practice, I added it. Didn't fix the issue though

Comment: @rycirese Then try this one viewPager.destroyDrawingCache() also.

Comment: No luck, same issue

Comment: @rycirese Sorry, I didn't see you use some library ButterKnife, please go on the website and see if there is a bit more info. Good luck! :) http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/